# Why can't I find/install the upgrade that I just discovered?

Tags: no-mans-sky

When exploring a planet you sometimes bump into outposts or shelter where they tend to have some gear or multitool upgrades (jetpack, stamina, shield, mining beam intensifier etc).

Just yesterday I discovered a technology to increase my shield to make it more resilient against cold, which was great since I am on a cold planet. However when looking to install the upgrade it was not there... Is this a bug or something else? I have not yet tested it out with other discoveries.

Comment: Are you looking in the right place, just as a sanity check. On the Exosuit Inventory, find an empty slot, and click the A Button (Xbox Controller) on it. The second tab should contain all the environmental protection shield blueprints.

Comment: Yup, been looking in every possible tab. Could it be that a discovery of a new technology is not the same as getting a blueprint? I have yet to test this theory and did not really pay attention at the start of the game to this fact.

Comment: I don't believe there's a difference between discovering a new technology, and gaining the blueprint for it, but I may not be paying enough attention to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug that pop ups occasionally/randomly when you try to learn a new tech. It will say "You already know this tech" when you really don't. The bug seems to happen most often when using the wall-mounted upgrade consoles. If this happens, you will be unable to get that specific tech from a wall-mounted upgrade console - You'll have to wait until you get the tech from some other source. A drop pod or an NPC, for example.

Source: [This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4y2qmo/known_blueprints_bug), my own experience

Since patch 1.07 this bug is now fixed, [see patch notes](http://www.no-mans-sky.com/log/#pc_1_07).

Comment: Wow, that is pretty annoying bug then. I'll try to pay attention during my playsession this evening if this happens again.

Comment: I've reported this issue to Hello Games, and I'm sure other have as well. Fingers crossed it gets solved soon.

Comment: While playing yesterday I actually started paying attention to getting the upgrades and I have to say this bug happens quite often. I came accross the Pulse Engine Sigma upgrade three times and each time it said I already knew this technology while I can't build it yet... Hope it gets fixed soon!

Comment: An update to this, Hello Games replied today and said that they've fixed this issue in the latest patch. http://www.no-mans-sky.com/log/